# Click "Allow" in iOS native popup

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am probably missing something here but I am trying to click "Allow" for a native popup in iOS11 +. If anyone has any idea on how to determine what the xpath is for this native popup or any other ideas it would save me a lot of headache!

I have tried to switch the correct context, NATIVE_APP I believe, then use an xpath locator click the option but no luck at all.

I think I am on the right track but the xpath just being incorrect.

xpaths I have tried are:

````
@label="Allow"
//*[. = 'Allow']
//*[contains(text(), 'Allow')]

```browser.contexts(async function (context) {
    browser.setContext(context['value'][0]); //switch to native

browser
.useXpath()
.click('@label="Allow"');
}
);```
````

Error message being,

An error occurred while running .click() command on <@label="Allow">: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

**Update**
The below works for iOS11 and iOS12, but is extremely slow for iOS11

```
browser.contexts(async function (context) {
  console.log("this is all the contexts: " + context.value);
  browser.setContext(context['value'][0]); //switch to native

  browser
     .useXpath()
     .click('//*[@name="Allow"]’);
}
);
```

iOS10
    browser.execute('mobile:alert', { 
    notification
   action: 'accept',
   buttonLabel: 'Allow'
    });

Comment: You are trying to bypass the system security. This is not possible. It could be a huge security issue if it could be done. Also, the popup is not part of the DOM and it's actually part of the browser. You can't access it.

Comment: `browser.contexts(async function (context) {
    browser.setContext(context['value'][0]);` should resolve the issue of it not being part of the DOM in the webview as I am switching to the 'NATIVE_APP' context. It seems to be able to be handled from an appium point of view http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/#mobile-alert however this is not working iOS10 onwards.

Comment: So... let me see if I understand this correctly. iOS is showing a pop-up asking the user for permissions for something your app is doing. And you want to just automatically click Allow without user input?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk correct. I know what the actions are. I know where the user will be taken to.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to click "Allow" for a native popup in iOS11

Are you describing a permissions dialog, like [a location, contact, or photos permission dialog](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/)?

If so, you cannot interact with these from your application. The user must explicitly tap an "Allow" button to grant permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @duskwuff, see my update which now seems to have resolved the issue.